# Laravel - HasMany relation not loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I'm having an issue with a `hasMany`-relation in my Laravel application.
I'm sure, it is a simple question, but currently I'm struggling with it and can't find the reason.

I have a Model called `LandingPage`:

```
<?php

namespace app\Models\LandingPage;

class LandingPage extends \App\Models\Base
{
    public $table = "landing_pages";

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'event_id',
        'url_id',
        'is_update_needed',
        'view',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'app_icon',
        'landing_page_url_base_path'
    ];

    ...

    public function app_info() {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\App\AppInfo::class, "landing_page_id", "id");
    }

    public function app_images() {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\App\AppImage::class, "landing_page_id", "id");
    }

    public function app_texts() {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\App\AppText::class, "landing_page_id", "id");
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is on `app_texts()`. I doesn't load the app_texts of my landing page.
As you can see there are similar relations `app_info` & `app_images`. I've copy/pasted the relation from `app_images` to `app_texts`. `app_images` is working fine.
Here is the Model of `AppText`:

```
<?php
namespace app\Models\App;

class AppText extends \App\Models\Base
{
    public $table = "app_texts";

    protected $fillable = [
        'text',
        'type',
        'landing_page_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    public function landing_page() {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\LandingPage\LandingPage::class, "id", "landing_page_id");
    }
}
```

In the database is everything correctly set up:

**landing_pages:**
[image]

**app_texts:**
[image]

I also can see in the Laravel Debugbar, that the query is not being executed to load the app_texts:

[image]

Have I forgotten something, or have I got something wrong?

### Update

The landing page is part of another Model (`guests`). I call there the property `landing_page`, but without calling the relations explicitly. It works for `app_images` or `app_info`, so I don't think, I need to call `app_texts` explicitly.

This is the controller section where it is called:

```
public function showEvent(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, string $eventName, string $guestIdentifierToken) {
        $guest = $this->guestRepository->getByIdentifierToken($guestIdentifierToken);
        if($guest != null) {
            if($guest->landing_page->is_update_needed == 1) {
                //...
                //do some stuff
            }
            return view('event.landingpage', [
                'eventUrl' => url()->current(),
                'guest' => $guest,
                'event' => $guest->event,
                'landingPage' => $guest->landing_page 
            ]);
        }
        else {
            return redirect('/notFound');
        }
    }
```

It works, if I call the property explicitly:

```
$guest->landing_page->app_texts = $guest->landing_page->app_texts;
```

But why do I need to this for `app_texts` and not for `app_images` or `app_info`?

Comment: Are you calling the `app_texts` relationship on your page?

Comment: where is the code that supposedly calls for app_texts ?

Comment: Not explicitly, but I do not call the other relationsships as well. So I don't think this is the reason...

Comment: Are you eager loading the other relationships then and forgetting to do so with this relationship?

Comment: Please see my update...

Comment: There must be something in your `event.landingpage` view calling the other relationships, or they are being eager loaded in your `LandingPages` model but not the `app_texts` relationship.

Comment: No, there the data is just passed to React with `window.guest = {!! json_encode($guest) !!}`. It is still a mystery why, but I will try to solve and post the solution here, if I find the reason.

Comment: " so I don't think, I need to call app_texts explicitly" , Im missing a part in your question, so the `app_texts` data is missing when you try to use it in your javascript? Seems like somewhere you are causing `app_info`&`app_images` to be loaded even though you think you didnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LandingPage` model has two `appends` on it:

```
protected $appends = [
    'app_icon',
    'landing_page_url_base_path'
];
```

When your `LandingPage` model is converted to json, these two fields will be included, meaning that their associated accessors will be called. My guess is that you are using your `app_info` and `app_images` relationships inside your `getAppIconAttribute()` and `getLandingPageUrlBasePathAttribute()` accessor functions.

Since the relationships are used in those accessors, they will be included in the json output. However, since the `app_texts` relationship is never used, it will not be included.

If you want your `app_texts` relationship included in your json output, you will need to load it before you convert to json. The quickest solution for you is to just load it in your inside your `showEvent()` function:

```
$guest->landing_page->load('app_texts');
```